# creating link to sub process in visio using c# or vba

Tags: c#, vba, interop, visio, visio2013

Hi i am creating visio shapes programatically using c#.
In visio am creating composite diagrams ( sub - process ) using the below code.

```
 Visio.Shape    ParentShape = myShape;
 ParentShape.CreateSubProcess();  //it will create a sub diagram for the shape
```

using this am creating  subprocess(composite) diagram for the shape.
But now i need to link a sub process diagram to one or more parent shapes.
 In Visio it can be simply done by clicking **Link to SubProcess** option.
But i want to acheive it in visio API..Is it possible to acheive it ..??

**Question is:**

How to assign a page to multiple shapes as sub-process in API .?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For linking a single page to multiple shape sub-process is done by adding the page name as hyperlink for that shapes , to which we need sub-process to be created.

```
 Visio.Hyperlink vsoHyperlink = ParentShape.AddHyperlink();
      vsoHyperlink.SubAddress = PageName;
```

> **ParentShape** - the shape for which the sup-process (or ) composite to be created.
>
> **PageName**- the name of the page or diagram in visio, which needs to be treated as sup-process (or ) composite